# Foundation 5.2.3 Top Bar Drop down not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Hi guys i am new for foundation 5 and i tried to make a top bar for my website but drop down is not working here is my code please help

i was googling all the day but i was not able to find a solution for this. please help me. is it possible to occur issue like this due to foundation issue?

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel = "icon" href = favi.gif type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
<title>Music Eka</title>
</head>
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
    </li>
     <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you haven't initialized foundation

add this at the end of your body.

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```